# C# DateTimeCompact and TimeCompact

Tags: datetime, datetime-format

Someone tell what is DateTimeCompact and TimeCompact, how its calculated?
So far I know each is 2 Byte value interpretable as Date and Time

Here an Example value:

```
0x40410001 = 01.02.2022 00:00:02
0x493ebf7d = 30.09.2026 23:59:58
```

Comment: Neither of those types are part of the .NET standard library, so at the very least this is missing a tag for whatever library or technology you found this in.

Comment: As it stands, this question is not related to c# at all. Please read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

I´ve found out, but do not know whether the DateTimeCompact and TimeCompact is a special type for this purpose and only is relevant for this one specification but its find of interesting so I want to share some knowledge :-)

DateTimeCompact is 2 Byte UShort value and can be interpreted in 16 Bits as followed:

```
F E D C B A 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
y y y y y y y m m m m d d d d d
```

So the value from the queston:

```
0x4041 0001 -> 0x4041 DateTimeCompact -> 0x0001 TimeCompact
0x493e bf7d -> 0x493e DateTimeCompact -> 0xbf7d TimeCompcat

0x4041

0b0100 0000 0100 0001
  yyyy yyym mmmd dddd

Year: 0100000 -> 32 
Month: 0010 -> 2
Day: 00001 -> 1
```

The year is calculated from 1990 so
Year 1990 + 32 = 2022 -> 2022.02.01

TimeCompact:

```
F E D C B A 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
h h h h h m m m m m m s s s s s

Time: 0001
0b0000000000000001 
  hhhhhmmmmmmsssss
Hourse: 0
Minutes: 0
Seconds: 1
```

But seconds are calculated as 2 seconds
So final: 2022.02.01 00:00:02